# OnClick, Com duas "Ações" no mesmo botão. PHP

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de fazer um botao que ao clicar realizasse a ação 1 do onclick e quando clicasse denovo realizasse a ação 2 e depois de clicar novamente realizasse a 1, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Para qual finalidade? Dependendo do que você tenha em mente, há modos mais práticos e simples de fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe N maneiras de realizar essa funcionalidade. Eu vou exemplificar utilizando um [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) ao elemento HTML para definir/sincronizar qual a ação que deve ser executada.

Como no exemplo abaixo.

```js
function test(element)
{
    if (element.getAttribute('data-action') == 1)
    {
        alert("Executando a ação 1...");
        element.setAttribute('data-action' , 2);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Executando a ação 2...");
        element.setAttribute('data-action' , 1);
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-action="1" onclick="test(this);" >ação</a>
```

O atributo `data-action` define qual action deve ser executada. Já a função `teste`, após executar a ação, altera o `data-action` para a próxima ação que será executada.

**Update**

Conforme descrito nos comentários, o que o autor quer é um efeito "toggle". Para alternar entre visível e não visível.

```js
function toggle(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggle('element-id');" >alternar</a>

<div id="element-id" >elemento</div>
```

Basicamente a função irá validar se na lista de `class` do elemento existe a `class` `hide`. Caso existir, irá removê-la. Do contrário, irá adicioná-la.

A class `hide`, por sua vez, define o `display` do elemento como `none`. É melhor utilizar uma `class`, ao invés de alterar diretamente o `display`, pois, alguns elementos podem possuir um display em específico, que será perdido caso você não o salve quando adicionar ele novamente ao elemento.

Comment: Queria fazer o seguinte. Com primeira ação -
onClick="document.getElementById('invi').style.display = '';" Como segunda ação - 
onClick="document.getElementById('invi').style.display = 'none';"

Comment: @GuilhermeFreitas isso não é o que a sua questão está solicitando/descrevendo. Entretanto, é bem mais fácil. Vou atualizar a resposta,

Comment: Ok muito obrigado, desculpe a dúvida ainda sou iniciante

Comment: @GuilhermeFreitas atualizado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode adicionar uma variável pra servir de flag, que recebe true/false, ou clicado, null, enfim.

Conforme ele clica no botão, você faz as verificações necessárias, e altera a flag.

Mas como nosso amigo comentou, dependendo do que você quer fazer, há métodos mais práticos.

Answer (score -1):

Guilherme, segue uma sugestão para isso, usando JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<input id="botao" type="button" onclick="Funcao1();>
```

Javascript:

```
function Funcao1(){
   // Faz o que você precisa

   // Altera a função do click para a função 2
   document.getElementById("botao").setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: Funcao2();" );
}

function Funcao2(){
   // Faz o que você precisa

   // Altera a função do click para a função 1
   document.getElementById("botao").setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: Funcao1();" );
}
```